# Monitor changes color randomly

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display

My monitor displays random colors like [this](https://dl2.pushbulletusercontent.com/Je8Dhcvh1NwkYpkeqGxN9KSendEncH9h/VID_20190131_151044.mp4).

Sometimes it does display the page, but it's glitched and in a few seconds, it will get back the color rotation like [this](https://dl2.pushbulletusercontent.com/jRsCoJbWwVA0Y3PjXUBZcOVuoNfRhfOf/VID_20190203_211645~2.mp4) and [this](https://dl2.pushbulletusercontent.com/FjOTmsxLFqlqShvLE5w8ukIBcd68Blq9/VID_20190203_213127.mp4).

I tried changing another laptop, changing another HDMI cable, changing to DP port, but the problem persists.

Comment: So you have established your monitor is faulty....

Comment: @davidgo I'm aware of that. But what seems to be the problem? Can it be fixed by myself?

Comment: If you are asking the question, I expect not - however monitor repairs would be outside of scope here.